# Mapbox iOS: Clusterproperties NSExpression all & any not working

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have a lot of features that all have a category. This can be either "5020" or "5021". I put this in the feature's attributes as NSString.

Now i want to add to my clusterproperties, that i have two bool-values "only_5020" and "only_5021". So if only one category is present, the right bool should be true.

I am trying to use this expression for this:

```
NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], "5020"]])
```

But it is always false. Also if i put "any" instead of "all" it is also false (but my features definatly have category 5020 available).

My whole source looks like that:

```
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: Constants.cluster_source,
                                    features: features,
                                    options: [.clustered: true,
                                              .clusterRadius: 50,
                                              .maximumZoomLevelForClustering: Constants.cluster_max_zoom,
                                              .clusterProperties: ["5019_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5019]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")],
                                                                   "5020_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5020]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")],
                                                                   "5021_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5021]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")],
                                                                   "5022_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5022]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")]]])
        style.addSource(source)
```

I manually create the features like that:

```
var feature: MGLPointFeature {
        get {
            let item = MGLPointFeature()
            item.identifier = self.itemId
            item.attributes["name"] = self.itemTitle
            item.attributes["category"] = self.cyclingType.rawValue
            item.attributes["isRoute"] = true
            item.coordinate = self.coordinate
            return item
        }
    }
```

Does someone maybe know whats going on?
I am using mapbox 5.9.0 for iOS.

Comment: Could you provide the example of the json object?

Comment: @IvanovDeveloper i create the features manually. i edited the snippet of it. the self.cyclingType.rawValue is an Integer.